Why these JMenuItems can't have ActionListener
When I create a JMenuItem with the help of a method everything works fine except for the ActionListener which does not work, (If you could recommend a manual to go into more detail about this, do not hesitate to send it)
    public JMenuBar menuBar;
    
    public JMenu mnArchivo, mnMante, mnVentas, mnConfig, mnAyuda;
    
    public JMenuItem itmSalir, 
                     itmConsulCocina, itmModCocina, itmListCocina,
                     itmVender, itmGenReport,
                     itmConfigDesc, itmConfigObse, itmConfigCantOp, itmConfigCuotDiaria,
                     itmAcercaDe;
    
    public Home() {
        setTitle("Tienda 1.0");
        setBounds(0, 0, 900, 600);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        
        mnArchivo = new JMenu("Archivo");
        menuBar.add(mnArchivo);
        
        mnVentas = new JMenu("Ventas");
        menuBar.add(mnVentas);
        
        //JMenuItem made with method (DOESN'T WORKS)
        addJMenuItem(itmSalir, "Salir", mnArchivo);
        
        //JMenuItem explicitly stated (WORKS)
        itmVender = new JMenuItem("Vender");
        itmVender.addActionListener(this);
        mnVentas.add(itmVender);
        
        setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void addJMenuItem(JMenuItem itm, String name, JMenu mn) {
        itm = new JMenuItem(name);
        itm.addActionListener(this);
        mn.add(itm);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //this doesn't changes color
        if(e.getSource() == itmSalir) {
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        //this changes color
        if(e.getSource() == itmVender) {
            getContentPane().setBackground(Color.pink);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Home home = new Home();
    }
}

I'm starting to use methods to save code (and to learn how to use them xP)

This goes back to the heart of how information is passed to/from methods.  Doing itm = new JMenuItem(name); inside addJMenuItem isn't going to assign the JMenuItem instance to the parameter value used externally to the method.  It's simply going to create a new reference, which no longer points to the original parameter, and which will, effectively, be lost when the method returns.
Essentially, when you pass an object to a method, the method can change the object properties, but, changing the reference to the object (such as assigning a new object or instance to it) will not be reflected when the method returns.
This is important, because when you do addJMenuItem(itmSalir, "Salir", mnArchivo);, itmSalir is still going to be null when the method returns.
This then means when you're actionPerformed method is called...
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //this doesn't changes color
    if(e.getSource() == itmSalir) {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    }
    //this changes color
    if(e.getSource() == itmVender) {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.pink);
    }
}

itmSalir will never be matched to the source, because itmSalir is null.
You can see this by adding some additional print statements to your code.
If you want to make use of this kind of factory method, you'd have to do something more like...
public JMenuItem addJMenuItem(String name, JMenu mn) {
    JMenuItem itm = new JMenuItem(name);
    itm.addActionListener(this);
    mn.add(itm);
    return itm;
}

Which you would then be used something like...
itmSalir = addJMenuItem("Salir", mnArchivo);

This is a core concept to how Java works.  See Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor for some more details.  You may also want to have a look at Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?
